# Why are apps not loading anything after a while of use (Nexus 5 | 16GB)?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, youtube, instagram, snapchat

Well the title says it. It happens to most apps that need an internet connection.
(Instagram, Youtube, Play Store, Whatsapp etc.) The browser works fine though.

But for example when I'm looking at my Instagram feed, after a while nothing loads anymore. Like wifi turned off or something. Or on Youtube after watching a few videos If I click on another video it starts not/infinite loading.

The solution to this is reopening the app, but this can be annoying as you have to find where you were again.

I couldn't find anything on Google and never heard anybody experiencing the same.
Is it because of my phone ? My wifi ? (3/4 connection most of time | 60mb/s) I do think other people didn't have this in my house but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I now have the Nexus 5X (Same simcard) and I got the same problem.

EDIT:
I noticed reconnecting to the WiFi is a solution as well, but this is still annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping the cache and data of that app in settings .

Comment: Wiping data is not a good recommendation here (and in general at least not without naming the consequences). OP already wrote "solution to this is reopening the app" – so data are obviously not the culprit.